# How to skip the first line in Node.js readline?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to read a file and skip its first line in an async function. I've tried `rl.next()` and `rl.once('line',()=>{})`, and those don't work. How to skip the first line?

```js
const fs = require('node:fs');
const readline = require('node:readline');

async function readfile(filename){
  const rs = fs.createReadStream(filename);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({input: rs});
  // not working: rl.next(), or rl.once('line',()=>{})
  for await (const line of rl) {

  }
}
```

Related question: the [document](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#rlsymbolasynciterator) says `rl` is an `AsyncIterator`, why doesn't it have a `next()` method?

Answer (score 1):

To keep it easy:

```js
async function readfile(filename){
  const rs = fs.createReadStream(filename);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({input: rs});

  let index = 0;
  for await (const line of rl) {
     if (index === 0 {
        continue;
     }
      
     // do what you have to do
     
     index++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `AsyncIterator` for `node:readline` is not recommended due to performance issues https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#rlsymbolasynciterator. Recommended method is `rl.on('line', listener)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `AsyncIterator` for `node:readline` is not recommended due to performance issues: [Node.js API documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#rlsymbolasynciterator).
Recommended method is `rl.on('line', listener)`.
You could use something like this:

```js
const fs = require('node:fs');
const readline = require('node:readline');

async function readfile(filename){
  const rs = fs.createReadStream(filename, {encoding: 'utf8'});
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: rs,
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
  });
  let isFirstLine = true;
  rl.on('line', (line) => {
    if (isFirstLine) {
      isFirstLine = false;
      return;
    }

    // do things with `line`

  });
  rl.once('close', () => {
    rs.close();
    rl.close();
  });
}
```